# Jquery - find closest text by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, find, closest

Here is my HTML and script.  I simply want to find the text of what is clicked, and include the text of it's previous element with a certain class, in the alert.  Elements are not necessarily children/parents here.

So, if Prince5 is clicked, the alert should read  King1: Queen3: Prince5

I'm close, but it's currently always giving the text as Queen1, since it's the first text in that column.

Any ideas?

```
<li class="king"><a href="#" >King1</a>            
<span class="column1">                    
<li><a href= "#" class="queen">Queen1</a></li> 
<li><a href= "#"> Prince1</a></li> 
<li><a href= "#"> Prince2</a></li>
<br>
<li><a href= "#" class="queen">Queen2</a></li> 
<li><a href= "#"> Prince3</a></li> 
<li><a href= "#"> Prince4</a></li>
<br>
<li><a href= "#" class="queen">Queen3</a></li> 
<li><a href= "#"> Prince5</a></li> 
<li><a href= "#"> Prince6</a></li>
</span>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("li a").click(function() {
    var three= $(this).text(),
    one = $(this).closest('.king').find('a:first').text();
    two = $(this).closest(".column1").find("a.queen:first").text();
    alert(one + ":" + two + ":" + three);
});
</script>
```

Comment: your looking for its siblings not its parent Closest() brings you to the parent.  Look at Prev() and Next()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with the HTML shown. A `span` is not a valid parent for the `LI` elements so I added a UL.

Basically you can go back up the ancestors of the clicked link, then sideways through previous siblings (that match .queen), then down again to the link on the first match:

```
$("li a").click(function () {
    var three = $(this).text(),
        one = $(this).closest('.king').find('a:first').text();
    two = $(this).closest("li").prevAll("li:has(a.queen)").first().find('a').text();
    alert(one + ":" + two + ":" + three);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/7q3e9p7g/1/

Comment: THANK YOU.  This worked perfectly.  No, the html is not the cleanest - but I must work around it at the moment.  Thanks again!